# Find first/last row "recursively" by group

Tags: r, data.table

I try to find a efficient way of finding the first and last line by group.

```
R) ex=data.table(state=c("az","fl","fl","fl","fl","fl","oh"),city=c("TU","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI"),code=c(85730,33133,33133,33133,33146,33146,45056))
R) ex
   state city  code
1:    az   TU 85730           
2:    fl   MI 33133           
3:    fl   MI 33133           
4:    fl   MI 33133           
5:    fl   MI 33146           
6:    fl   MI 33146           
7:    oh   MI 45056
```

I would like to find the first and last for each variable of a group

```
R) ex
   state city  code first.state last.state first.city last.city first.code last.code
1:    az   TU 85730           1          1          1         1          1         1
2:    fl   MI 33133           1          0          1         0          1         0
3:    fl   MI 33133           0          0          0         0          0         0
4:    fl   MI 33133           0          0          0         0          0         1
5:    fl   MI 33146           0          0          0         0          1         0
6:    fl   MI 33146           0          1          0         1          0         1
7:    oh   MI 45056           1          1          1         1          1         1
```

As far as I know `data.table` cannot easily help for things like this because `by="state,city,code"` would look at `4` triplets.

The only way I know would be to look for first/last.code in a by="state,city,code" then first/last.city in a by="state,city".

---

This is what I meant:

```
applyAll <- function(DT, by){
    f<- function(n, vec){ return(vec[1:n]) }
    by <- lapply(1:length(by), FUN=f, by)
    out <- Reduce(f=firstLast, init=DT, x=by)
    return(out)
}
firstLast <- function(DT, by){
    addNames <- paste(c("first", "last"),by[length(by)], sep=".")
    DT[DT[,list(IDX=.I[1]), by=by]$IDX, addNames[1]:=1]
    DT[DT[,list(IDX=.I[.N]), by=by]$IDX, addNames[2]:=1]
    return(DT);
}
```

Result by: `applyAll(ex,c("state","city","code"))` but this would make NUMEROUS copies of `DT`, my question is then, is there someting scheduled or already existing such that we cant get first/last by groups. (This is fairly vanilla for `SAS` or `kdb` or `SQL`)

In `SAS`:

```
data DT;
    set ex;
    by state city code;
    if first.code then firstcode=1;
    if last.code then lastcode=1;
    if first.city then firstcity=1;
    if last.city then lastcity=1;
    if first.state then firststate=1;
    if last.state then laststate=1;
run;
```

Comment: Reagarding your last sentence, what is wrong with that?

Comment: That you need to repeat the instruction of finding first then last N times if you have N grouping variables

Comment: I am curious why you want this. There might be a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the question :

> For a set of columns (x,y,z) I'd like to add an integer column marking the position of the first item of each group `by="x"`, `by="x,y"` and `by="x,y,z"` (three new columns). The 1st row of each new column will always be 1 because that's always the first item of the first group. I'd also like to add a further 3 columns marking the last item by each of the same 3 groupings. I might have many more than just 3 groupings, though, so is something programatic possible please?

then how about :

```
ex=data.table(state=c("az","fl","fl","fl","fl","fl","oh"),
              city=c("TU","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI","MI"),
              code=c(85730,33133,33133,33133,33146,33146,45056))
ex
   state city  code
1:    az   TU 85730
2:    fl   MI 33133
3:    fl   MI 33133
4:    fl   MI 33133
5:    fl   MI 33146
6:    fl   MI 33146
7:    oh   MI 45056

cols = c("state","city","code")
for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
  ex[,paste0("f.",cols[i]):=c(1L,rep(0L,.N-1L)),by=eval(head(cols,i))] # first
  ex[,paste0("l.",cols[i]):=c(rep(0L,.N-1L),1L),by=eval(head(cols,i))] # last
}
ex
   state city  code f.state l.state f.city l.city f.code l.code
1:    az   TU 85730       1       1      1      1      1      1
2:    fl   MI 33133       1       0      1      0      1      0
3:    fl   MI 33133       0       0      0      0      0      0
4:    fl   MI 33133       0       0      0      0      0      1
5:    fl   MI 33146       0       0      0      0      1      0
6:    fl   MI 33146       0       1      0      1      0      1
7:    oh   MI 45056       1       1      1      1      1      1
```

But as @Roland commented, there's probably a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

And, as requested, here's what should be a faster solution using `.I` and `.N` :

```
cols = c("state","city","code")
for (i in seq_along(cols)) {
  w = ex[,list(f=.I[1],l=.I[.N]),by=eval(head(cols,i))]
  ex[,paste0(c("f.","l."),cols[i]):=0L]  # add the two 0 columns
  ex[w$f,paste0("f.",cols[i]):=1L]       # mark the firsts
  ex[w$l,paste0("l.",cols[i]):=1L]       # mark the lasts
}
```

It should be faster because the grouping is done just once per column, and lots of small vectors are not created (no call to `c()` or `rep()` for each group) unlike the first solution.

Comment: This looks good. I was wondering if `data.table` hold something like `.I`,`.GRP`... (or a combinaison of it) that could have helped achieving this faster, I guess I know now. Cheers guys.

Comment: @statquant Are you saying this solution is slow and you're wondering if it could be faster? Your English isn't very clear. It sounds as if you're not 100% delighted. And I'm still waiting for the "fairly vanilla" solutions in the other languages you mentioned which do this task so easily; e.g. SQL and SAS (the SAS solution you posted was written out column by column).

Comment: slow is relative, this is the best I've seen so far, and I can't do faster myself. I was wondering if it could use .variables because using this is usually the fastest way, but you know better... 
About the vanilla I think the SAS code is fairly good with regard to simplicity not in number of lines of code but as far as syntax is concerned. Concerning my english I plead guilty, I guess it is common to a lot of us non-native speakers...

Comment: @statquant Ok thanks for clarification, I'll add solution using .variables.  But in terms of the SAS syntax I had your complaint in mind: "That you need to repeat the instruction of finding first then last N times if you have N grouping variables". Which looks to be what you're doing in SAS.

Comment: It made sense at that point, I don't really want to go back the whole flow of comments. The point is that your solution is quick, programmatic efficient (without useless copies of objects). That's what I was looking for, cherry on the cake would be to use .variables to leverage the internal grouping process of data.table

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but you can certainly have more than one column in the index:

```
ex[, list(first=head(code, 1), last=tail(code, 1)), by=c("state", "city")]
   state city first  last
1:    az   TU 85730 85730
2:    fl   MI 33133 33146
3:    oh   MI 45056 45056
```

---

You can automate this over your groups like this:

```
by <- c("state", "city", "code")
byList <- lapply(seq_along(by), function(i)by[sequence(i)])
lapply(byList, 
       function(i) ex[, list(first=head(code, 1), last=tail(code, 1)), by=i] )

[[1]]
   state first  last
1:    az 85730 85730
2:    fl 33133 33146
3:    oh 45056 45056

[[2]]
   state city first  last
1:    az   TU 85730 85730
2:    fl   MI 33133 33146
3:    oh   MI 45056 45056

[[3]]
   state city  code first  last
1:    az   TU 85730 85730 85730
2:    fl   MI 33133 33133 33133
3:    fl   MI 33146 33146 33146
4:    oh   MI 45056 45056 45056
```

Comment: This is precisely what I am trying to do in an automated fashion, If I have a group of 10 I'd rather avoid writing 10 lines

Comment: @Andrie: `byList <- Reduce(c,by,accumulate = TRUE)`, but still not exactly what the OP wants according to the intended output in the question.